# Get precise location and size of TaskBar

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

How can I accurately get the Size (Height) and Location of the Windows TaskBar in a Windows Forms app?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is how:

```
[DllImport("user32.dll")]
public static extern IntPtr FindWindow(string lpClassName, string lpWindowName);

[DllImport("user32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
static extern bool GetWindowRect(IntPtr hwnd, out RECT lpRect);

[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
public struct RECT
{
    public int Left;        // x position of upper-left corner
    public int Top;         // y position of upper-left corner
    public int Right;       // x position of lower-right corner
    public int Bottom;      // y position of lower-right corner
}
```

How to get the location and size of `taskbar`:

```
//Get the handle of the task bar
IntPtr TaskBarHandle;
TaskBarHandle = FindWindow("Shell_traywnd", "");

RECT rct;

//Get the taskbar window rect in screen coordinates
GetWindowRect(TaskBarHandle, out rct);
```

Comment: A couple of things to be careful of: If there are multiple monitors then the taskbar may be positioned on a monitor other than the primary one, so the X or Y positions may be negative. And if the monitor is using a dpi greater than 96, then all sorts of strange things are possible, also depending on the Windows version.